# How to find the index of multiple size value based on the value

Tags: javascript, typescript

data = {
boxNoTo: 1,
boxNoFrom: 1,
size: 'M',
}

array = [{
size: 'M',
},{
size: 'M',
},{
size: 'S,M,L,XS',
boxNoTo: 1,
boxNoFrom: 1,
country: 'CA',
name: 'Josh'
}]

what I did is like this

```
const INDEX = array.findIndex((x) => {
      if (x.size.split(',').length > 0) {
        return (
          x.size.split(',').filter((y) => y === data['size'])[0] ===
          data['size'] &&
          x.boxNoFrom === data['boxNoFrom'] &&
          x.boxNoTo === data.boxNoTo
        );
      } else {
        return (
          x.size === data['size'] &&
          x.boxNoFrom === data['boxNoFrom'] &&
          x.boxNoTo === data.boxNoTo
        );
      }
    });
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the index of

```
 {
 size: 'S,M,L,XS',
 boxNoTo: 1,
 boxNoFrom: 1,
 country: 'CA',
 name: 'Josh'
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```js
const data = { boxNoTo: 1, boxNoFrom: 1, size: 'M', };
const array = [{ size: 'M', },{ size: 'M', },{ size: 'S,M,L,XS', boxNoTo: 1, boxNoFrom: 1, country: 'CA', name: 'Josh' }];


const { size, ...rest } = data;
const index = array.findIndex(item => 
  item.size.split(',').includes(size) 
  && Object.keys(rest).every(key => item[key] === rest[key])
);

console.log(index);
```

Comment: I updated the data. please check

Comment: @BeginnerCoder This solution still works despite the changes.